# is there a way to distribute xml exchange server add on on mobile intranet (outlook application) users

Tags: exchange-server, add-on, intranet, exchange-server-2010

I have an xml exchange server add on for reporting emails to the Cyber security team in the company , it is working find except for mobile users on the intranet , i can find anyway to distribute these addons automatically to all the mobile users on my intranet , is there any way way possible to do so  ?

I am still  checking if it is posssible or not , but i can not find anyway on documentations anywhere

Comment: Are you talking about Office web add-ins?

Comment: no i am talking about exchange server

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy Office web add-ins for selected users or OU. To assign add-ins to tenants, use the Exchange admin center to upload a manifest directly, either from a file or a URL, or add an add-in from AppSource. To assign add-ins to individual users, you must use Exchange PowerShell. For details, see [Add-ins for Outlook in Exchange Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/add-ins-for-outlook-2013-help).

Be aware, Outlook add-ins require Exchange Server 2013 or later.

Comment: thank you  for your reply , but i am doing the same thing for the normal users , mobile users on intranet are not supported to distribute through the exchange admin